# How to send form data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, multipartform-data, form-data

I am able to get to the server but unable to post my form data.
How should I post the form data with the https request?
I am using form-data library for form-data, and https request for post call.
When I run the following code, I am able to reach the service, but the service gives a response saying that the form data is not submitted.

```js
var https = require('https');
var FormData = require('form-data');
//var querystring = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');
var form = new FormData();

connect();

function connect() {
    username = "wr";
    password = "45!"

    var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
    var options = {
        hostname: 'trans/sun.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/transfer/upload-v1/file',
        method: 'POST',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': auth,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            //'Content-Length': postData.length
        }
    };

    form.append('deviceId', '2612');
    form.append('compressionType', 'Z');
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('/Mybugs.txt'));

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        //console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            console.log(d)
        });
    });

    req.write(form + '');
    req.end();

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You never link your form to your request. Check this example provided with the [form-data documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data)

```
var http = require('http');

var request = http.request({
  method: 'post',
  host: 'example.org',
  path: '/upload',
  headers: form.getHeaders()
});

form.pipe(request);

request.on('response', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```